# <c:when> test always returns false with jsp

Tags: jsp, jstl

I don't know why this code always return false for the first condition and goes to the `otherwise` for every loop.

Here's a part of the code:

```
<c:forEach var="Attribut" items="${ExecQuery.rows}">
            <tr>
                <td> <c:out value="${Attribut.Systeme_source}"/></td>
                <c:set value="${Attribut.Systeme_source}" var="Source"/>
                <c:choose>
                <c:when test="${Source eq 'DATALAKE' }"> <c:out value= "${Attribut.COUNTRPARTY }"/></c:when>
                <c:otherwise><c:out value="null"/></c:otherwise>
                </c:choose>
```

For every loop, I got `null` even if I have `DATALAKE` as source system.

Does anyone have an idea about that?

Comment: Check if your set variable is null before your when condition: <c:if test="${ empty Attribut.Systeme_source }">EMPTY</c:if>

Comment: The Attribut.System_source is actually not empty. I test it and it showed up all the sources. So when i set the variable, this one is not empty.